# Communication between inline JavaScript and Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using Node.js and I want to send a request which contains an input value to the server when a button is pressed.

So here's my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="input" action="/onclick" autocomplete="off">
        <button id="button">Send</button>
        <script>
            let input = document.getElementById('input');

            document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                let value = input.value;

                if (value) {
                    let data = {};
                    data.title = 'getValue',
                    data.message = value;

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'/onclick',
                        data: JSON.stringify(data),
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: (responseData) => {
                            console.log('Success!');
                        },
                    });

                    input.value = null;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my server.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/onclick', (req, res) => {
    console.log('body: '+ JSON.stringify(req.message));
    res.send(req.message);
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

The code doesn't throw any error (it returns `Success!` in browser console) but the problem is that in the Node.js shell it sends `body: undefined` instead of the input value.

Do you know how to fix that ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Isn't it `req.body` instead of `req.message`?

Comment: You are right, it's actually ```req.body``` that is needed, but it still returns 'undefined'.

Comment: Add a body parer middleware

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your server.js to access the request body:

```
app.use(express.json());
```

And use `req.body` instead of `req.message` to access the request body

Comment: Now it returns ```body: {}```

Comment: There is another problem in the POST request you are sending, add this field `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` in the ajax request.

Comment: Here's my Ajax request : ```$.ajax({
 url:'/onclick',
data: JSON.stringify(data.message),
type: 'POST',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: (responseData) => {
console.log('Success !');
console.log(data.message);
},
 });``` but it throws the error : ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0```

Comment: That's because you've changed the 'data' field to `JSON.stringify(data.message)` instead of `JSON.stringify(data)`. data.message is a simple string instead of the full object you want to send to the server.